# Roadmap after RingCT and Kovri

Tags: development-roadmap

After RingCT and Kovri, which new features are on the road-map to be implemented?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The design and development goals are on the website: https://getmonero.org/design-goals/

RingCT still needs performance and efficiency improvements, but more than that it opens up a way to do multisignature transactions, so that has to be built.

Beyond that, there are loads of critical features and improvements, and lots more that will have to fleshed out on the research side of things before we could even attempt to write code.